# Replace Nth occurrence of a character in a string with something else

Tags: r, regex

Consider `a = paste(1:10,collapse=", ")` which results in

```
a = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10"
```

I would like to replace every n-th (say 4-th) occurrences of "," and replace it with something else (say "\n"). The desired output would be:

```
"1, 2, 3, 4\n 5, 6, 7, 8\n 9, 10"
```

I am looking for a code that uses `gsub` (or something equivalent) and some form of `regular expression` to achieve this goal.

Comment: Are you trying to learn `gsub` or regex ?

Comment: The regex is simple, `((?:\d+, ){3})(\d+),` write back `$1$2\\n`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can replace `((?:\d+, ){3}\d),` with `\1\n`

You basically capture everything till fourth comma in group1 and comma separately and replace it with `\1\n` which replaces matched text with group1 text and newline, giving you the intended results.

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zebqLb/1)**

**[R Code demo](https://rextester.com/XCCR51033)**

```
gsub("((?:\\d+, ){3}\\d),", "\\1\n", "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10")
```

Prints,

```
[1] "1, 2, 3, 4\n 5, 6, 7, 8\n 9, 10"
```

**Edit:**

To generalize above solution to any text, we can change `\d` to `[^,]`

**[New R code demo](https://rextester.com/OQW75303)**

```
gsub("((?:[^,]+, ){3}[^,]+),", "\\1\n", "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10")
gsub("((?:[^,]+, ){3}[^,]+),", "\\1\n", "a, bb, ccc, dddd, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000")
```

Output,

```
[1] "1, 2, 3, 4\n 5, 6, 7, 8\n 9, 10"
[1] "a, bb, ccc, dddd\n 500, 600, 700, 800\n 900, 1000"
```

Comment: Can we replace \d to something else to make it more general? Let say instead of single digits, we may have some random string such as `"a, bb, ccc, dddd, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000"` and we want to replace every 4-th comma with '\n'.

Comment: Sure, we can replace `\d` with `[^,]+`

Comment: @Mahmoud: I've updated my answer to make it general and not just for digits.

Answer (score 2):

`regmatches` as yet another alternative:

```
a <- "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10"

fn <- ","
rp <- "\n"
n <- 4

regmatches(a, gregexpr(fn, a)) <- list(c(rep(fn,n-1),rp))
a
#[1] "1, 2, 3, 4\n 5, 6, 7, 8\n 9, 10"
```

As a function:

```
a <- "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10"

replN <- function(x, fn, rp, n) {
    regmatches(x, gregexpr(fn, x)) <- list(c(rep(fn,n-1),rp))
    x
}
replN(a, ",", "\n", 4)
#[1] "1, 2, 3, 4\n 5, 6, 7, 8\n 9, 10
```

You could even extend this to be vectorised over the replacement argument:

```
a = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10"

replN <- function(x,fn,rp,n) {
    sel <- rep(fn, n*length(rp))
    sel[seq_along(rp)*n] <- rp
    regmatches(x, gregexpr(fn, x)) <- list(sel)
    x
}
replN(a, fn=",", rp=c("1st","2nd"), n=4)
#[1] "1, 2, 3, 41st 5, 6, 7, 82nd 9, 10"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using both `regex` and `gsub`.

```
a = paste(1:10,collapse=", ")
x <- gsub("([^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*),", '\\1\n', a)
x
#> [1] "1, 2, 3, 4\n 5, 6, 7, 8\n 9, 10"
```

Answer (score 1):

regex is the best alternative, nontheless here's another approach without regex

```
> str_vec <- strsplit(a, " ")[[1]] 
> where <- seq_along(str_vec) %% 4 == 0
> str_vec[where] <- sub(",", "\n", str_vec[where])
> paste(str_vec, collapse=" ")
[1] "1, 2, 3, 4\n 5, 6, 7, 8\n 9, 10"
```

Answer (score 0):

This one can be replace with a string instead of a character.
I did a function that you can use easily :)

[A demo here to understand the regex](https://regex101.com/r/chn5EA/1)

```r
> a = paste(1:10,collapse=", ")
> a
[1] "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10"
> # if you want the 2nd occurence
> gsub("(.*?,.*?),(.*)", "\\1\n\\2", a)
[1] "1, 2\n 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10"
> # if you want the 3rd occurence
> gsub("(.*?,.*?,.*?),(.*)", "\\1\n\\2", a)
[1] "1, 2, 3\n 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10"
> # if you want the 4rd occurence
> gsub("(.*?,.*?,.*?,.*?),(.*)", "\\1\n\\2", a)
[1] "1, 2, 3, 4\n 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10"
> # if you want the last occurence
> gsub("(.*,.*),(.*)", "\\1\n\\2", a)
[1] "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9\n 10"
> 
> 
> replace.occurence <- function(x, pattern, replacement, which.occu) {
+   if( which.occu == "last" ) {
+     gsub(paste0("(.*", pattern, ".*)", pattern, "(.*)"), paste0("\\1", replacement, "\\2"), x)
+   } else {
+     gsub(paste0("(.*?", paste0(rep(paste0(pattern, ".*?"), which.occu - 1), collapse = ""), ")", pattern, "(.*)"), paste0("\\1", replacement, "\\2"), x)
+   }
+ }
> 
> replace.occurence(a, pattern = ",", replacement = "\n", which.occu = 2)
[1] "1, 2\n 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10"
> replace.occurence(a, pattern = ",", replacement = "\n", which.occu = 3)
[1] "1, 2, 3\n 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10"
> replace.occurence(a, pattern = ",", replacement = "\n", which.occu = 4)
[1] "1, 2, 3, 4\n 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10"
> replace.occurence(a, pattern = ",", replacement = "\n", which.occu = "last")
[1] "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9\n 10"
> 
> replace.occurence(a, pattern = ", 3, 4,", replacement = ", 4, 3,", which.occu = 1)
[1] "1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10"
```